# return different results in different lines

Tags: xquery, flwor

I found similar questions but I tried them and I did not get it to work.
I got  "ventas" collection and inside the collection I have fours diferents xml files.

These are the xml files:

`productos.xml`

```
<productos>
<product categoria="A" pvp="20">
    <codigo>A2015</codigo>
    <nombre>Cuchillas</nombre>
    <stock>100</stock>
</product>
<product categoria="A" pvp="5">
    <codigo>A2005</codigo>
    <nombre>Laminas</nombre>
    <stock>57</stock>
</product>
<product categoria="B" pvp="15">
    <codigo>B1501</codigo>
    <nombre>Comida</nombre>
    <stock>50</stock>
</product>
<product categoria="C" pvp="20">
    <codigo>C2020</codigo>
    <nombre>Sopa</nombre>
    <stock>100</stock>
</product>
<product categoria="A" pvp="100">
    <codigo>A1001</codigo>
    <nombre>Tela</nombre>
    <stock>100</stock>
</product>
</productos>
```

`clientes.xml`

```
<clientes>
<clien numero="01">
    <nombre>Juan</nombre>
    <poblacion>Madrid</poblacion>
    <tlf>111111111</tlf>
    <direccion>Alcala</direccion>
</clien>

<clien numero="02">
    <nombre>Luis</nombre>
    <poblacion>Barcelona</poblacion>
    <tlf>2222222222</tlf>
    <direccion>Canalets</direccion>
</clien>

<clien numero="03">
    <nombre>Sara</nombre>
    <poblacion>Madrid</poblacion>
    <tlf>01012101212</tlf>
    <direccion>Sol</direccion>
</clien>
</clientes>
```

`facturas.xml`

```
<facturas>
<factura numero="100">
    <fecha>01/01/01</fecha>
    <importe>25</importe>
    <numcliente>01</numcliente>
</factura>
<factura numero="101">
    <fecha>01/01/01</fecha>
    <importe>40</importe>
    <numcliente>01</numcliente>
</factura>
<factura numero="102">
    <fecha>01/01/01</fecha>
    <importe>4</importe>
    <numcliente>02</numcliente>
</factura>
<factura numero="103">
    <fecha>01/01/01</fecha>
    <importe>80</importe>
    <numcliente>02</numcliente>
</factura>
<factura numero="104">
    <fecha>01/01/01</fecha>
    <importe>75</importe>
    <numcliente>01</numcliente>
</factura>
</facturas>
```

`detallefacturas.xml`

```
<detallefacturas>
<factura numero="100">
    <codigo>Z</codigo>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>A2015</codigo>
        <unidades>2</unidades>
        <importe>0</importe>
    </producto>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>A2005</codigo>
        <unidades>1</unidades>
        <importe>0</importe>
    </producto>
</factura>
<factura numero="101">
    <codigo>X</codigo>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>B1501</codigo>
        <unidades>5</unidades>
        <importe>0</importe>
    </producto>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>A2015</codigo>
        <unidades>4</unidades>
        <importe>0</importe>
    </producto>
</factura>
<factura numero="102">
    <codigo>Y</codigo>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>C2020</codigo>
        <unidades>15</unidades>
        <importe>0</importe>
    </producto>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>A2015</codigo>
        <unidades>2</unidades>
        <importe>0</importe>
    </producto>
</factura>
<factura numero="103">
    <codigo>Q</codigo>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>C2020</codigo>
        <unidades>2</unidades>
        <importe>0</importe>
    </producto>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>A2015</codigo>
        <unidades>2</unidades>
        <importe>0</importe>
    </producto>
</factura>
<factura numero="104">
    <codigo>H</codigo>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>A1001</codigo>
        <unidades>10</unidades>
        <importe>0</importe>
    </producto>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>A2015</codigo>
        <unidades>2</unidades>
        <importe>0</importe>
    </producto>
</factura>
<factura numero="105">
    <codigo>U</codigo>
    <producto descuento="0">
        <codigo>C2020</codigo>
        <unidades>2</unidades>
        <importe>0</importe>
    </producto>
</factura>
</detallefacturas>
```

Last result:

```
<detalle>
    <codigo>A2015</codigo>
    <nombre>Cuchillas</nombre>
    <cant>2</cant>
    <pvp>20</pvp>
    <importe/>
</detalle>
<detalle>
    <codigo>A2005</codigo>
    <nombre>Cuchillas</nombre>
    <cant>1</cant>
    <pvp>20</pvp>
    <importe/>
</detalle>
<detalle>
    <codigo>A2015</codigo>
    <nombre>Laminas</nombre>
    <cant>2</cant>
    <pvp>5</pvp>
    <importe/>
</detalle>
<detalle>
    <codigo>A2005</codigo>
    <nombre>Laminas</nombre>
    <cant>1</cant>
    <pvp>5</pvp>
    <importe/>
</detalle>
```

In the last attemp it returns the data in different elements but duplicate all the data. In each element it uses each pvp.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change

```
for $productos in collection("/ventas")/productos
let $nombre := $productos/product[codigo=$codigos/codigo]/nombre,
    $pvp := $productos/product[codigo=$codigos/codigo]/@pvp
```

to

```
for $producto in collection("/ventas")/productos/product[codigo=$codigos/codigo]
let $nombre := $producto/nombre,
    $pvp := $producto/@pvp
```

As for the further problems raised in a comment, well, you haven't shown your input structure and I think you are trying to solve various problems with one question. Do you now have the right number of `detalle` elements with the right `nombre` child data and the right `pvp` value?

For the `codigo` to be correct I think you are better off to use

```
for $p1 in collection("/ventas")/productos/product,
    $p2 in collection("/ventas")/detallefacturas/factura[@numero="100"]/producto where $p1/codigo = $p2/codigo
let $nombre := $producto/nombre,
    $pvp := $producto/@pvp
return 
<detalle>
        <codigo>{data($p2/codigo)}</codigo>
        <nombre>{data($nombre)}</nombre>
        <cant>{data($p2/unidades)}</cant>
        <pvp>{data($pvp)}</pvp>
        <importe></importe>
</detalle>
```

It might help to edit your question with sample data or ask a new question with sample data on that problem.

Comment: Now I get two different elements but with the values repeated. I edited the original post.

Comment: You are rigth. I updated the first question and added all the data with the data structure. Also I tried your last code but it duplicate de elements.

Comment: @EBG, I see you have now edited the question text to contain the sample data but it seems you have removed any description of what you want to achieve. Please edit the question to reinsert a clear description of the result you want.